# Is it possible to send payments with a Plaid API developer account?

Tags: plaid

Title says it all. Is it possible to send payments with a Plaid API developer account?

I am using developer account access tokens in Google Sheets and don't have a great way of hiding them. I'm hoping the developer accounts are read only so that *if* someone hacked me, they wouldn't be able to transfer money out of my accounts if they got a hold of an access_token.

Answer (score 1):

Access tokens should always be stored securely. If an attacker has your access token, as well as your client_id and secret, they can make Plaid API calls on your behalf to get data for a specific Item.

The specific data that can be obtained from an access token depends on what products you are enabled for in Production. If you are enabled for Auth, this would include account number and routing number. This information can be used to request an ACH fund transfer via, e.g., your a website (note that this information is also printed on all checks in your checkbook). Finally, if an ACH transfer was made in this way, you would have grounds to have it reversed for fraud.

So while it might be possible for an attacker to use your access_token in conjunction with other hidden information (your client_id in secret) to get information that they could use to request a funds transfer out of your account, there are a number of hurdles for this attack vector. An attacker would also need your secret (or Plaid login info), and even then they would still only get the information that is present on every check you write, and there is a mechanism in the ACH system to reverse fraudulent transfers.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the response! This was very helpful.